# How to check if a specific alarm is triggered in AlarmManager

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-notifications

I'm trying to add reminder option to my note-taking app and I'm using AlarmManager to show notifications.
for the PendingIntent `requestCode` and `notificationManager.notify` id, I'm using the note ID saved in the database.
The app works fine and notifications are shown as expected. There's a TextView showing the selected alarm time for each note.
 But how can I check the triggered Alarm and know which note is the Alarm for, so I can remove the TextView showing the selected time like the image below?

[image]

Comment: Put the note ID as an extra on the `Intent` that you create your `PendingIntent` with.

Comment: @MikeM. I am doing exactly like this. but how is this going to help solving the problem?

Comment: "I am doing exactly like this." – You didn't mention that in the question. Beyond that, I'm not really sure what you're asking, now. How else do you expect to differentiate notes other than their IDs?

Comment: @MikeM. I want to remove the alarm TextView when the alarm for that note is triggered. I do have the note ID. but when and where should I check that?

Comment: OK, I think I see what you mean, now. I was confused by your description. That image you've shown is _not_ the `Notification`, but rather the alarm's entry in your `Activity`, yeah? And you want to be able to remove, or strikethrough, that entry when the alarm fires?

Comment: @MikeM. Yes. that's what I meant